# Find dy/dx given an equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, differentials

Here's a homework problem from the Coursera course [Calculus: Single Variable by Robert Ghrist](https://www.coursera.org/course/calcsing)

> Find the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ from the equation $x \tan y - y^2 \ln x=4$

I wanted to check my work using Mathematica so I tried this:

```
Dt[x Tan[y] - y^2 Log[x] == 4];
% /. {Dt[y] -> dy, Dt[x] -> dx};
Reduce[{%, dy/dx == z}, z]
```

On my system (Mathematica 9, Windows 7), this computation seems to hang.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

**Edit:**

I'm also interested in why `Reduce` doesn't handle the problem well when used as above whereas `Solve` handles it just fine (see answers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `Dt` accepts a second argument that specifies what symbol corresponds to the independent variable in the differentiation. In your case, that's `x`. The derivative you're looking for would then be written `Dt[y, x]`.

So you just need to do this:

```
Solve[Dt[x Tan[y] - y^2 Log[x] == 4, x], Dt[y, x]]

(*
==> {{Dt[y, x] -> (y^2 - x Tan[y])/(
   x (-2 y Log[x] + x Sec[y]^2))}}
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `D` directly but define `y` as `y[x]` and solve for `y'[x]` as follows.

```
Solve[D[x Tan[y[x]] - y[x]^2 Log[x] == 4, x], y'[x]]
```

> ```
> {{y'[x] -> (-x Tan[y[x]] + y[x]^2)/(
>    x (x Sec[y[x]]^2 - 2 Log[x] y[x]))}}
> ```

And if you want the answer without the `y[x]` appearing you can use a replacement rule:

```
Solve[D[x Tan[y[x]] - y[x]^2 Log[x] == 4, x], y'[x]] /. y[x] -> y
```

> ```
> {{y'[x] -> (y^2 - x Tan[y])/(
>    x (-2 y Log[x] + x Sec[y]^2))}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just as you started:

```
 expr1 = Dt[x Tan[y] - y^2 Log[x] == 4]

(* -((y^2 Dt[x])/x) - 2 y Dt[y] Log[x] + x Dt[y] Sec[y]^2 + 
  Dt[x] Tan[y] == 0  *)
```

Divide the both parts by Dt[x]:

```
    expr2 = Map[Divide[#, Dt[x]] &, expr1] // Apart
```

(*  (-y^2 Dt[x] - 2 x y Dt[y] Log[x] + x^2 Dt[y] Sec[y]^2)/(x Dt[x]) + 
      Tan[y] == 0  *)

Replace Dt[y]/Dt[x] by z:

```
 expr3 = expr2 /. Dt[y] -> z*Dt[x] // Simplify

  (*  x z Sec[y]^2 + Tan[y] == (y (y + 2 x z Log[x]))/x *)
```

Now find z:

```
    Solve[expr3, z]

(*  {{z -> (y^2 - x Tan[y])/(x (-2 y Log[x] + x Sec[y]^2))}}  *)
```

Done.